# How do I convert Hexadecimal string into single-precision float

Tags: c#, .net, string, floating-point, hex

I have a 4 byte hexadecimal code of a string type that I need to convert into a float, conforming to the IEEE 754 [Single-Precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

I think Java had a library to do this with ease but I'm not sure if C# has one. What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Convert to byte array. Bitconverter

Comment: @RameshDurai: Why would BitConverter.ToInt32 be useful? [`BitConverter.ToSingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle), surely.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Agreed.BitConverter.ToSingle is Helpful. Sorry for the Wrong answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it sounds like you're starting from a hex string:

```
string hex = "0a0b0c0d";
byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
{
    // THEN DEPENDING ON ENDIANNESS
    raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    // OR
    raw[raw.Length - i - 1] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
}
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(raw, 0);
```

If you are actually starting from a `byte[]`, then you can skip the first few steps.

Comment: raw = BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)) is a shortcut.

Comment: @HansPassant hmmmm... true enough, I guess. Actually, I'd be tempted to just `unsafe` the conversion from `int` to `float` at that point ;p

Comment: @HansPassant actually, you raise an interesting point, in that `int.Parse` uses a different endianness to how I've expanded it. Updated to show both. For the OP: for a cheeky example of the `unsafe` flip (assuming the **second** `Convert` usage shown): `int num = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); float f = *((float*)&num);`

Comment: This code gives me the error `Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.`